# Is it a bad practice to pass parameters through a IoC Container?

Tags: dependency-injection, unity-container

**TL;DR Is it considered a bad practice to pass *run-time* parameters to a constructor by using the container?**

As an example, I'm building a WCF solution that has services hosts built dynamically using a `ServiceHostFactoryBase` implementation. This factory is my [Composition Root](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot/); It access Unity, set it up and uses the container to resolve a `ServiceHost`. However, this ServiceHost needs to access some configuration in a database, and it uses the "constructorString" to identify this configuration.

Since Unity is the guy creating the instance of my `ServiceHost`, I see no other solution than passing the parameter through a `ParameterOverride`. **But I don't like it.** The parameter is not a dependency, it's a parameter, found at run-time. **Furthermore**, the `ServiceHost` depends on yet another class that also needs the "constructorString". So I will rely on Unity to pass this around.

I'm using Unity 3 as my IoC container.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it considered a bad practice to pass run-time parameters to a
>   constructor by using the container?

Yes it is. The rule is to inject compile-time dependencies using constructors and runtime dependencies using method calls.

A 'compile-time dependency' is a value that is known at compile-time or at configuration time (when the system starts and the dependencies are wired using the container). This allows the container to build up the object graph for you.